# For-loop not printing all the array in php

Tags: php

Below here is code. when I'm trying to submit the from I got the array value till on 164 and rest are not coming. total array value is 225.

```
<?php 
if($maxproducts=="") { $maxproducts=30;}
for($i=1;$i<=225;$i++) { ?>
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
<td valign="top">Product Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo "pcode[$i]" ?>" value="<?php echo $pcode[$i]; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td valign="top">$<br>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo "price[$i]"; ?>"  value="<?php echo $price[$i]; ?>" size="1">
</td>
<td valign="top">Product/Sales URL:<br>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo "plink[$i]"; ?>"  value="<?php echo $plink[$i]; ?>" size="25">
</td>
<td valign="top">Aff. Resource Page:<br>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo "presource[$i]"; ?>"  value="<?php echo $presource[$i]; ?>" size="20">
</td>
<td valign="top">Download URL:<br>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo "pthanks[$i]"; ?>"  value="<?php echo $pthanks[$i]; ?>" size="27">
</td>
<td valign="top">Autoresponder Listname:<br>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo "pAR[$i]"; ?>" value="<?php echo $pAR[$i]; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: is data coming from db? where the form code?

Comment: no it's coming from a file. file name is config

Comment: You are submitting in which method POST or GET??

Comment: I'm Using post method

Comment: Try using `foreach()` instead of `for()`. At times, array keys may not be in the order we're expecting them.

Comment: Try updating your php.ini file `max_input_vars = 5000`

Comment: let me try, give me 5 mins

Comment: I'm using cpanel then where i can update ?

Comment: I have added the mac_input_vars = 5000 in php.ini but it's not working .

Comment: Any Idea Guys ??

Comment: Try to print only the ones that are missing making `$i` starting from 165 in your loop. Are they being printed?

Comment: That was the right ans:-
Update your php.ini file max_input_vars = 5000

Comment: max_input_vars = 5000 right ans